# Handling unrolled loop remainder

Tags: performance, optimization

Good day.

I'd like to ask for contribution on tricks to handle unrolled loops leftovers, with a caveat that loops are fairly small, 1-3 times the unrolling factor, eg:

EG.  given unrolling factor of B

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < N-N%B; i += B) {
    ...
}
// remainder
for (; i < N; ++i) {
    ...
}
```

if B is 2, I can do the following:

```
// remainder
if (N%2) {
    ....
}
```

But what is a good way to handle `B>2`

Comment: Hard to see why a trick is needed, you loop N / B times, remainder is N % B.  You'd normally leave this up to the code generator, it already knows how to unroll loops.

Comment: Well there's always *[Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device)* but there's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: In C or any language? Predicated instructions can be nice for this in some assembly languages.

Comment: @Mike I was thinking something along those lines.  The loops are short so that remainder has significant ovrhead.

Comment: @harold C is preferred but may be yu can give some examples with assembly?

Comment: @Anycorn: Do you know if a good percent of time is spent in that exact code? If there's a function call inside the loop, or anything that takes more than several cycles, it's probably not worth the bother. You could profile, or as I do, just pause it a few times. If you catch it a few times in the increment/compare/jump instructions of the loop, then it's worth unrolling, otherwise not.

Comment: @Anycom: Besides, you don't have to do remainder. Like if B is 8, just loop `for(; i < N - 7; i += 8)`.

Comment: @Mike the loop overhead is about 5% - not a whole lot but I need to get the most performance.  No functions calls in the body, purely float ops.  Unrolling the entire loop helps but I want to avoid code size bloat.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if (N%2)` can be easily extended to any unroll factor:

```
for (; i < N-B+1; i += B) {
    x1; x2; ... xB;
}
if (i < N) {
    x1;
if (i < N-1) {
    x2;
    ...
if (i < N-B+2) {
    xB;
}}}
```

For small unroll factors this may be more efficient than second loop or Duff's device.

This version looks better. gcc 4.6 compiles almost the same code out of it:

```
if (i++ < N) {
    x1;
if (i++ < N) {
    x2;
    ...
if (i++ < N) {
    xB;
}}}
```

And this version may be more optimal if `B` is a power of two. At least gcc compiles better code for it. Also it is definitely the best if `N` is a constant. But if neither `N` is a constant, nor `B` is a power of two, advantage of this method is not so obvious because of less efficient remainder computation (which means usually several instructions, including multiplication):

```
if (N%B > B-2) {
    x1;
if (N%B > B-3) {
    x2;
    ...
if (N%B > 0) {
    xB;
}}}
```